# Delete duplicates in mysql when based on values from 3 columns matching

Tags: mysql

I have the query below that shows me duplicates in my table. I would like to know how can i turn this into a delete query to delete these duplicate rows but leaving just one. My table does have a auto increment id column.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user_tmp AS t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT name, activity, class, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM tbl_user_tmp
WHERE user = 'test' AND disregard = 0
GROUP BY name, activity, class
HAVING cnt > 1
) AS t2
ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.activity = t2.activity AND t1.class = t2.class

WHERE user = 'test' AND disregard = 0
GROUP BY t1.name, t1.activity, t1.class
```

I have tried the query below and seems to work, but im afraid im missing something. does it look correct?

```
delete from tbl_user_tmp 
where user='test' AND id not in
(
      select minid from 
      (select min(id) as minid from tbl_user_tmp where user='test' group by name, activity, class) as newtable
)
```

Comment: I assume you want to keep one row?

Comment: yes. udpated question with query i tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT`. 
Example:

```
DELETE FROM users
LIMIT 2;
```

Now you just need to set `COUNT - 1` as your limit ;)